# Can I dynamically generate & remove content from jQuery Accordion before tab is opened and closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using the [Accordion control](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible) from jQuery UI. The contents of the accordion are generated dynamically from a user's data with JavaScript and then inserted into accordion via the `innerHTML` property before it is created. This approach works, but has one drawback. Since I'm generating HTML for all tabs the resulting accordion may be somewhat sluggish. For instance, in my example with 256 accordion tabs and some extensive HTML for each tab, it was performing somewhat slow on my older laptop.

So I was curious, for the sake of optimizing performance, is it possible to attach HTML content to the accordion's tab right before it's open? And a second question, can I also remove it right after the tab is closed?

Just to provide more details, my accordion is created as such:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: nActiveTab
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `beforeActivate` and `activate` methods, as described in the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-beforeActivate).

```
beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
    var el = ui.newPanel[0];
    if (el) el.innerHTML = returnContent(el.id); // Opening
},
activate: function (event, ui) {
    var el = ui.oldPanel[0];
    if (el) el.innerHTML = "" // Closing
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ag0gw7cu/

Comment: Very cool. Thanks. I need to try it on my actual content before I mark it as the answer.